# Using the Spotify SDK in iOS using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

Spotify's beginner tutorial is only in Objective-C https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/, but using this along with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeO00YdJ3cE I was able to get my development environment set up properly,  however the SDK's methods (stuck on log in) have changed since that video was posted...can anyone tell me how to convert the log in methods into Swift?

I'll be happy to open source my code once i get it running.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about iOS, but if you get your code written I'd be very much interested in hearing about it! I had a quick look around the internet, and it looks like [this repo](https://github.com/dbruzzone/SpotifySwiftly) might help you out?

Comment: You should consider adding some of your code so people can help spot an issue.

Comment: The accepted answer links to Swift code isn't that enough?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://medium.com/@elonrubin/ios-spotify-sdk-swift-3-0-tutorial-b629af4b889d) a great tutorial on implementing the iOS Spotify SDK in Swift. 
Without looking at your code, what you're looking for is likely the following:

```
if player == nil {
    self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()

    self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
    self.player!.delegate = self
    try! player!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
    self.player!.login(withAccessToken: session.accessToken)
}
```

This will then call the following delegate function when the login returns:

```
func audioStreamingDidLogin(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!) {

}
```

Once that delegate function is called you can start using the player to play tracks.

Comment: I have done player it was working before few days but I am not able to play now. it shows me following error. `failed to play: Optional(Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk.playback Code=1 "The operation failed due to an unspecified issue." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation failed due to an unspecified issue.}) `